# BASH File Movement

Tags: linux, bash, file, scripting

I have BASH Function

```
MoveToTarget() {
    #This takes to 2 arguments: source and target
    echo ""$1"  "$2""
    cp -r "$1" "$2"
    rm -r "$1"
}
```

And I'm passing these values in:
 *First argument: (source)*

> /home/family/.PROGNAME/updater/update

*Second argument: (target)*

> /home/family/Desktop/client/src

Right now, the folder `/update` is being moved into `/home/family/Desktop/client/src` creating `/home/family/Desktop/client/src/update`. How can I get it so the contents of `/home/family/.PROGNAME/updater/update` are moved into `/home/family/Desktop/client/src`? (Re-writing over any existing files), rather than just moving the folder?

Some additional information, the following AutoIt code accomplishes what I need.

```
 DirCopy($source, $target, 1)
 DirRemove($source, 1)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `mv`?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `mv`?

Comment: Your echo line probably does not do what you expect. You want `echo "$1"'  '"$2"` or `echo "$1  $2"`; as things stand whitespace in `$1` and `$2` are being collapsed unexpectedly.

Comment: @Sorpigal, I bet that rsmith really wants "\"$1\"  \"$2\""

Answer (score 3):

```
cp -rf /home/family/.PROGNAME/updater/update/* /home/family/Desktop/client/src
```

or in your script:

```
cp -rf "$1"/* "$2"
```